# PressMouseButton with value = 2 does not work in lua

Tags: lua, macros, logitech-gaming-software

I wrote some code in lua for my logitech mouse, but I don't understand why the PressMouseButton(2) doesn't work, if I were to write any other value like 1 or 3 those keys would work, I would like to press the middle mouse button (the click of the wheel, so to speak).
This is the affected part of the code.

```
function OnEvent(event, arg)
    if event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 5 then
        PressMouseButton(2)
        Sleep(math.random(30, 100))
        ReleaseMouseButton(2)
        Sleep(math.random(30, 100))
    end
end
```

PS. In key assignment, the middle key is set as default.

Mouse Model: Logitech G203 Prodigy.

Where am I doing wrong?

EDIT: If I had to test the macro in a browser, the PressMouseButton(2) returns me back to the previous page, but I don't understand why.

Comment: It should work.  What is your software: LGS of GHUB?

Comment: GHUB.

I realized now that if I had to test the macro in a browser, the PressMouseButton(2) returns me back to the previous page, but I don't understand why. I tried to change the value with values 4 and 5, thinking that my mouse had different values, but it doesn't work anyway.

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff If you have LGS or GHUB could you try my code in a browser? If it works correctly it should change your cursor icon to a page with the scrollbar.

Comment: I have tested your script on my G402 mouse.  Everything is OK on LGS.  But on GHUB `PressMouseButton(2)` simulates button4 instead of middle button, and `PressMouseButton(4)` and `PressMouseButton(5)` do not work at all.  This is obviously a bug in GHUB.  Please report to Logitech.

Comment: Unable to find a specific section for reporting bugs, I sent an error report directly from the GHUB application writing the bug in the description